# How to send large custom object to .net webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services, video, out-of-memory, httptransportse

I am able to send custom object to my .net webservice and my webmethod is working absolutely fine. I tested that code on multiple phone and result was success but when I was trying it on samsung mobile it started to give me exception.

I found that problem is MemoryOutOfException which is occuring because I have recorded large size of video and trying to convert that into byte[] but I was expected to record less quality video which is working in Micromax and Motorola but not in samsung (rest brands I don't know yet).

```
takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,
            MYVIDEOQUALITY);
```

so here is the some of the solution I think I should have:
1. Either record less size video from `Camera Intent` in all mobile(not working in samsung).
2. Or code your video upload method in such way that it will upload video in chunks. but I have to send more information about the video so I have created custom object to handle it and I have also implemented `KVMSerializable` and used `Marshal` also. Now I don't know how to send Large Custom object in chunks.

I have seen [this](http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/android-code-to-upload-download-large-files-to-server-2/) but I don't find I can send addition information along with it. it is send only video file alone.

If i am not clear enough please let me know what more information I should provide.

Here is the code that I am using to upload video :

```
private String SaveMedia(String Email, byte[] Media, String MediaType,
            String MediaExt) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                HelpMeConstant.WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, "SaveMedia");
    //  Log.i(TAG, "Email : " + Email + ", Media : " + Media                + "MediaType : " + MediaType + ",MediaExt : " + MediaExt);

        MediaAvidance mediainfo = new MediaAvidance();
        mediainfo.EmailId = Email;
        mediainfo.Media = Media;
        mediainfo.MediaExt = MediaExt;
        mediainfo.MediaType = MediaType;

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("avidanceinfo");
        pi.setValue(mediainfo);
        pi.setType(mediainfo.getClass());

        request.addProperty(pi);

        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    //  Log.i("SaveMedia", "Serialising..");
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.headerOut = HelperMethod.addAuthentication();
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                HelpMeConstant.SOAP_ADDRESS);

        Object response = null;

        try {
        //  Log.i("SaveMedia", "Calling service..");
            httpTransport.call(HelpMeConstant.SOAP_ACTION + "SaveMedia",
                    envelope);
    //      Log.i("SaveMedia", "getting response..");
            response = envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
    //      Log.e("SaveMedia", "I got an error :", exception);
            response = exception.toString();
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance for your response.

Comment: First send your custom object's other data as you normally would. Then send the video data in chunks.

Comment: can you show my any example? would this way my webmethod will be able to handle it. I have no idea how to do this in android and in webservice. Can you explain more for both android and webservice side. my webmethod looks like `public string METHODNAME(CUSTOMTYPE videowithpatameter){};`